# Why i am getting wrong result on taking input from user using javacc tool while parsing a statement?

Tags: java, io, javacc

When i am typing `java AssignStatement`

```
a=10+20*30
```

it asks me to enter one more statement after which I got

> Syntax checking failed

How to take input from user or through a file then? Here is my Source Code:

```
PARSER_BEGIN(AssignStatement)

public class AssignStatement      
{                              
  public static void main(String s[])        
  {
    try
    {
      AssignStatement as=new AssignStatement(System.in);
      as.StartSymbol();
      System.out.println("Syntax checking successfully");
    }
    catch(Throwable e)
    {
     System.out.println("Syntex checking failed");
     e.getMessage();
    }
  }
}

PARSER_END(AssignStatement)

 SKIP: {"" | "\t" | "\n" | "\r" }
 TOKEN:{ "(" | ")" | "+" | "*" | ":="| <NUM: (["0"-"9"])+> | <ID:(["0"-"9"])+>
       }

 void StartSymbol(): {}
 {
      (AStmt())*<EOF>
 }

 void AStmt(): {}
 { 
  LOOKAHEAD(2) <ID> "=" AStmt() 
  | Term() ("+" Term())*
 }

 void Term(): {}
 {
  Factor() ("*" Factor())*
 }

 void Factor(): {}
 {
  <NUM> 
  | <ID> 
  | "(" AStmt() ")"
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token manager throws an exception because no token can start with the letter "a".

Comment: I made the following corrections as u told and now i am getting the following errors which i am not able to find out in my AssignStatement.jj file After i typed this :C:\javaccprog\AssignStatement>java AssignStatement "a=10+20*30" Error Came Syntex checking failedLexical error at line 1, column 1. Encountered: "\"" (34) , after : "